# Angular $location. How could be parsed a query string in html5Mode(true) if user submit an URL with hashbang?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing a search page and have a requirement to *store all selected filters and other state in the URL*, so users can share results of their job.

I use angular $location.search() for updating and parsing of the URL. Location provider settings is follow:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

The problem begins when *user of legacy browser shares a link with hashbang to a user with a modern browser*. In such case $location.search() will return nothing.

As I understand the reason is in html5 mode after "#" starts $location.hash() and not $location.search(). But what is the goal of hashPrefix('!')? I thought it should solve such issue...

How could I parse a query string in html5Mode(true) if user submit an URL with hashbang?

Comment: I almost hate to suggest this, but you could try purl.js to parse the query string.  I used it today and it worked well.  https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl

Comment: Thanks for purl.js. Unfortunately the problem was solved as html5Mode(false)..

Comment: It is not an answer it is another way that is not desirable

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you were to set html5Mode to true, that handles all the routing within Angular, but it doesn't reflect how the server is routing to your application. You might have routes already set up for the hashbangs now, but what if you also provides the routes on the server without them?

From what I understand, if you have html5Mode set to true and a legacy browser doesn't support it, it'll automatically fallback to the hash tag routing. If someone were to capture that URL, then share it with a friend and you had support on your server to properly convert the query, route and deep link to your Angular application for either circumstance, it seems like you'd be covered.